# Changing the order status for Unirgy Gift Certificate

Tags: magento, status

I am using Unirgy Gift Certificate on a magento installation.

While ordering physical products, if a payment fails on my payment gateway, default order status on the backend is 'Pending', but if the product is a Gift Certificate, and the payment fails on the payment gateway the order status remains 'Processing', which is also the default order status for normal items paid normally.

This is creating a confusion for my finance team at the backend.

I have tried to manually set the order status to pending in the authorise method, just before redirecting to the payment gateway, but whatever I do, the status always goes to processing.

Any pointers?

> **I did ask the support and they said that since the Gift Certificate is a virtual product, magento does not need to ship it and hence the
>   order status becomes pending automatically.**

Comment: yes, paid extension, contact support

Comment: I did ask the support and they said that since the Gift Certificate is a virtual product, magento does not need to ship it and hence the order status becomes pending automatically.

Comment: I solved the above problem by making a custom module on top of unirgy that keeps track of whether a gift certificate has been paid for or not. Then a cron job that is scheduled every 5 minutes Holds the orderid for unpaid gift certificates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above problem by making a custom module on top of unirgy that keeps track of whether a gift certificate has been paid for or not. Then a cron job that is scheduled every 5 minutes Holds the orderid for unpaid gift certificates.